# Autowrap widgets to new line in flutter

Tags: layout, dart, flutter

I have 5 widgets with different sizes which would overflow if placed next to each other.

I am looking for a layout helper class that limits the widgets to the horizontal space and auto-wraps the widgets instead to a new line. First I was looking for a grid view but prefer instead a view which is independent since all elements have different widths. A multi line text field does actually already that, I just need the same approach with my widgets. Any ideas?

```
<Widget>[
    new RaisedButton(child: const Text('Foo')),
    new RaisedButton(child: const Text('Foo Bar')),
    new RaisedButton(child: const Text('Foo Bar Bas')),
    new RaisedButton(child: const Text('F')),
    new RaisedButton(child: const Text('B'))
]
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The `Wrap` widget is what you need:

```
return Wrap(
      children: <Widget>[
        new RaisedButton(child: const Text('Foo')),
        new RaisedButton(child: const Text('Foo Bar')),
        new RaisedButton(child: const Text('Foo Bar Bas')),
        new RaisedButton(child: const Text('F')),
        new RaisedButton(child: const Text('B'))
      ],
    );
```

Also you can add the properties `runSpacing` and `spacing` to your `Wrap` widget to give more space between your items in horizontal and vertical.

```
Wrap(
            runSpacing: 5.0,
            spacing: 5.0,
```

[image]

Comment: what about text??

Comment: Wow. Flutter does have a widget for everything. Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for! It Wraps the buttons nicely onto a second row if they overflow the width of they parent.

Comment: For my use-case RichText with TextSpan was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using the Wrap widget it will shift automatically your child widgets to the next line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).