# how to make row enter new line if width is filled

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a container which contains a row .. this row has set of items .. i want when the items in the row reach the end of the container width.. to start a new row inside the container ..

this is what am trying now:

```
Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Container(
                            //height: 100.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              color: Color(0xFF2CB57D),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0, left: 5.0),
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(
                                    CustomFont.multiplication_2,
                                    size: 11.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "hhhhhh",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      /*fontSize: 8.0*/ fontSize:
                                    ScreenUtil().setSp(fontSize['9'][globals.platform]),
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            //height: 100.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              color: Color(0xFF2CB57D),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0, left: 5.0),
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(
                                    CustomFont.multiplication_2,
                                    size: 11.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "hhhhhh",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      /*fontSize: 8.0*/ fontSize:
                                    ScreenUtil().setSp(fontSize['9'][globals.platform]),
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            //height: 100.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              color: Color(0xFF2CB57D),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0, left: 5.0),
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(
                                    CustomFont.multiplication_2,
                                    size: 11.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "hhhhhh",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      /*fontSize: 8.0*/ fontSize:
                                    ScreenUtil().setSp(fontSize['9'][globals.platform]),
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            //height: 100.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              color: Color(0xFF2CB57D),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0, left: 5.0),
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(
                                    CustomFont.multiplication_2,
                                    size: 11.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "hhhhhh",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      /*fontSize: 8.0*/ fontSize:
                                    ScreenUtil().setSp(fontSize['9'][globals.platform]),
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            //height: 100.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              color: Color(0xFF2CB57D),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0, left: 5.0),
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(
                                    CustomFont.multiplication_2,
                                    size: 11.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "hhhhhh",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      /*fontSize: 8.0*/ fontSize:
                                    ScreenUtil().setSp(fontSize['9'][globals.platform]),
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        .......
                          ),
                        ],
                    )
                ),
```

this returns this:

[image]

I want the last item in the row instead of being cropped to be displayed in the next row and so on ..

How to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491379/8101634

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autowrap widgets to new line in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490835/autowrap-widgets-to-new-line-in-flutter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be use Wrap Widget.

For Example :

```
Wrap(
      runSpacing: 0,
      spacing: 5,
      children: tagsList
                    .map((tags) => Chip(
                           onDeleted: () {
                            setState(() {
                              tagsList.remove(tags);
                            });
                          },
                          deleteIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.cancel,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          label: Container(
                              constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                                  maxWidth:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 70.0),
                              child: Text(
                                tags,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              )),
                          backgroundColor: ColorsHelper.skyDark(),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              )
```

And tagsList is List of String

```
List<String> tagsList;
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. i didn't know about the Wrap widget x_x