# Flutter - Display grid of buttons more dynamically

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm a little new to Flutter and new to working with UI. I am trying to display a set of radio buttons for the days of the week and would like to have the boxes containing each day fit the length of the text without shrinking the text. Then I would like to show all of the boxes in a set, but have them nicely fit together. Here's what I have now followed by what I would like to have:
[image]

[image]

The boxes in the second picture should have the different days and some of them would be wider than others, but that's my rough visualization of it.

I've been trying different combinations of sized, fitted, and limited boxes for the individual boxes and a gridview vs. a column with two rows to display the set of boxes.

Here's the code that I currently have. I appreciate any insights or explanations that anyone may have for working with Flutter layouts.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class TimeRadioModel {
  bool isSelected;
  String timeText;

  TimeRadioModel(this.isSelected, this.timeText);
}

class TimeRadioItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final TimeRadioModel item;
  TimeRadioItem(this.item);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LimitedBox(
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          item.timeText,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          color: Colors.amber,
          border: item.isSelected ? Border.all(width: 0.1) : null,
          boxShadow: item.isSelected
              ? [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                    spreadRadius: 2,
                    blurRadius: 3,
                    offset: Offset(1, 1.5),
                  ),
                ]
              : null,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTimeRadio extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomTimeRadioState createState() => _CustomTimeRadioState();
}

class _CustomTimeRadioState extends State<CustomTimeRadio> {
  List<TimeRadioModel> timeChoices = new List<TimeRadioModel>();

  final currTime = DateTime.now().weekday;
  // m = 1, t = 2, w = 3, th = 4, f = 5, s = 6, su = 7

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (currTime == 1) {
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Today'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tomorrow'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Wednesday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Thursday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Friday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Saturday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Sunday'));
    } else if (currTime == 2) {
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Today'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tomorrow'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Thursday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Friday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Saturday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Sunday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Monday'));
    } else if (currTime == 3) {
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Today'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tomorrow'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Friday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Saturday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Sunday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Monday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tuesday'));
    } else if (currTime == 4) {
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Today'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tomorrow'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Saturday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Sunday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Monday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tuesday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Wednesday'));
    } else if (currTime == 5) {
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Today'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tomorrow'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Sunday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Monday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tuesday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Wednesday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Thursday'));
    } else if (currTime == 6) {
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Today'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tomorrow'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Monday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tuesday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Wednesday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Thursday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Friday'));
    } else {
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Today'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tomorrow'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Tuesday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Wednesday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Thursday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Friday'));
      timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Saturday'));
    }
    timeChoices.add(TimeRadioModel(false, 'Anytime'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      width: 200,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < timeChoices.length - 4; i++)
                IconButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 1, 2, 1),
                  icon: new TimeRadioItem(timeChoices[i]),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      timeChoices.forEach((element) {
                        element.isSelected = false;
                      });
                      timeChoices[i].isSelected = true;
                    });
                  },
                ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              for (int i = 4; i < timeChoices.length; i++)
                IconButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 1, 2, 1),
                  icon: new TimeRadioItem(timeChoices[i]),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      timeChoices.forEach((element) {
                        element.isSelected = false;
                      });
                      timeChoices[i].isSelected = true;
                    });
                  },
                ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try looking at the **Wrap** widget. More info here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Comment: You can look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490835/autowrap-widgets-to-new-line-in-flutter

Comment: Wrap did exactly what I was looking for with the set of boxes. Thank you!! Is there a way to create the boxes for each day so that they size according to the text inside of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I was able to figure it out with the help of previous responses. To make my day boxes size according to their text, in the TimeRadioItem widget I used a sized box that calculated its width from the length of the text:

```
return SizedBox(
      width: item.timeText.length * 9.0,
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          item.timeText,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 4, 0, 4),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          color: Colors.amber,
          border: item.isSelected ? Border.all(width: 0.1) : null,
          boxShadow: item.isSelected
              ? [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                    spreadRadius: 2,
                    blurRadius: 3,
                    offset: Offset(1, 1.5),
                  ),
                ]
              : null,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I was then able to get the days to display properly as a set in my CustomTimeRadio widget by using Wrap and a GestureDetector instead of an IconButton:

```
return SizedBox(
      width: 250,
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < timeChoices.length; i++)
            GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 1, 2, 1),
                child: new TimeRadioItem(timeChoices[i]),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  timeChoices.forEach((element) {
                    element.isSelected = false;
                  });
                  timeChoices[i].isSelected = true;
                });
              },
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set it with a wrap instead of `row`

```
  Wrap(
        children: [
          for (int i = 4; i < timeChoices.length; i++)
            IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 1, 2, 1),
              icon: new TimeRadioItem(timeChoices[i]),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  timeChoices.forEach((element) {
                    element.isSelected = false;
                  });
                  timeChoices[i].isSelected = true;
                });
              },
            ),
        ],
      )
```

read more about Wrap widget in here
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-wrap-widget-e1ee0b005b16

Comment: This worked for arranging the set of boxes. Thank you! Is there a better way to build my TimeRadioItems so the box it creates is sized around the length of the text inside of it?

Comment: you mean you want to set size of container according to its text?